# glReadPixels is showing error with PyQt5. with GLUT Window it is working properly

Tags: python, opengl, opengl-es, pyqt5

I am developing a software in which I have an OpenGL window. I am creating the GUI of the software using `PyQt5` and for the opengGL Window I am using `QOpengGLWidget` and for object selection, I am using [**Stencil** **Buffer**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Object_selection) and reading **STENCIL_INDEX** as the following function on `mousePressEvent(self, event)`:

`id = glReadPixels(event.x(), self.height - event.y() - 1, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT)`

but this is not working when I am using with Qt5 GUI and showing following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akv26/Desktop/internProject/Main/opengl.py", line 92, in mousePressEvent
    val = glReadPixels(event.x(), self.height - event.y() - 1, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT)
  File "/home/akv26/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/images.py", line 371, in glReadPixels
    imageData
  File "/home/akv26/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 402, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
  File "/home/akv26/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenGL/error.py", line 232, in glCheckError
    baseOperation = baseOperation,
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glReadPixels,
    cArguments = (
        183,
        228,
        1,
        1,
        GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
        GL_FLOAT,
        array([[0.]], dtype=float32),
    )
)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and here is the code for my custom `QOpenGLWidget`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QOpenGLWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from math import *


class MyGLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):

    def initializeGL(self):
        glutInit()

        glClearColor(1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT1)
        glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)

        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)

    def resizeGL(self, w, h):
        self.height=h
        if h==0:
            h=1
        ratio =  w * 1.0 / h

        # Use the Projection Matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)

        # Reset Matrix
        glLoadIdentity()

        # Set the viewport to be the entire window
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h)

        # Set the correct perspective.
        gluPerspective(45.0, ratio, 0.1, 100.0)

        # Get Back to the Modelview
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

    def paintGL(self):
        glClearStencil(0)
        glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)

        glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)
        glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE)

        ambientColor = [0.2,0.2,0.2,1.0]
        glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientColor)

        lightColor0 = [0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0]
        lightPos0 = [0, 0, -10.0, 1.0]
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor0)
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos0)

        lightColor1 = [0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0]
        lightPos1 = [-1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0]
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor1)
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, lightPos1)

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluLookAt(-5,  5, -5, 0, 0,  0, 0.0, 1.0,  0.0)

        self.drawSome()

    def drawSome(self):
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, -1)

        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0)
        glNormal3f(0,0,-1)
        glVertex3f(-1,-1,0)
        glVertex3f(-1,1,0)
        glVertex3f(1,1,0)
        glVertex3f(1,-1,0)

        glEnd()

        glTranslatef(0,0,0)
        glColor3f(0.5,0,0)
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 2, -1)
        glutSolidCube(1.0)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        id = glReadPixels(event.x(), self.height - event.y() - 1, 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT)
        print(id)
```

and the same is working properly when I am using this with GLUT window as following:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from math import *
import numpy as np


window_width=0
window_height=0

def changeSize(w, h):
    global window_height, window_width
    window_width=w
    window_height=h
    # Prevent a divide by zero, when window is too short
    # (you cant make a window of zero width).
    if h==0:
        h=1
    ratio =  w * 1.0 / h

    # Use the Projection Matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)

    # Reset Matrix
    glLoadIdentity()

    # Set the viewport to be the entire window
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h)

    # Set the correct perspective.
    gluPerspective(45.0, ratio, 0.1, 100.0)

    # Get Back to the Modelview
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)


def drawSome():

    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, -1)

    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0)
    glNormal3f(0,0,-1)
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,0)
    glVertex3f(-1,1,0)
    glVertex3f(1,1,0)
    glVertex3f(1,-1,0)

    glEnd()

    glTranslatef(0,0,0)
    glColor3f(0.5,0,0)
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 2, -1)
    glutSolidCube(1.0)

def renderScene():

    glClearStencil(0)
    glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)

    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE)

    ambientColor = [0.2,0.2,0.2,1.0]
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientColor)

    lightColor0 = [0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0] #Color
    lightPos0 = [0, 0, -10.0, 1.0]
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor0)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos0)

    lightColor1 = [0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0]
    lightPos1 = [-1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0]
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor1)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, lightPos1)

    # Clear Color and Depth Buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    # Reset transformations
    glLoadIdentity()
    # Set the camera
    # gluLookAt(x,  1.0, z, x+lx, 1.0,  z+lz,   0.0, 1.0,  0.0)
    gluLookAt(-5,  5, -5, 0, 0,  0, 0.0, 1.0,  0.0)

    drawSome()

    glutSwapBuffers()

def mouse(button, state, x, y):

    global window_height
    id = glReadPixels(x, window_height - y - 1, 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT)
    print(id[0][0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA)
    # glutInitWindowPosition(100,100)
    glutInitWindowSize(320,320)
    glutCreateWindow("Lighthouse3D - GLUT Tutorial")
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5)
    # register callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene)
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize)
    glutMouseFunc(mouse)
    # glutTimerFunc(0, Timer, 0)

    # here are the new entries
    glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1)

    # OpenGL init
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1)
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)

    glutMainLoop()
```

**How to resolve the problem with QT5 GUI ?**

Comment: Your code assumes that the mouseClick event in both libraries is executed at the same time. Probably qt executes it somehow in parallel to your render code, thus your OpenGL state could be anything.

Comment: Also note, that a QOpenGLWidget does not render directly into the backbuffer but into a intermediate FBO which is then used in the Qt compositing process.

Comment: @BDL, can you provide the code that can help me to sort out this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there's no current OpenGL context when you call `glReadPixels`.  You're `mousePressEvent` should probably call [`QOpenGLWidget::makeCurrent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#makeCurrent)...

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):

    # Make the OpenGL context associated with this `QOpenGLWidget` current. and dont forget self
    self.makeCurrent()

    id = glReadPixels(event.x(), self.height - event.y() - 1, 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT)
    print(id)
    self.doneCurrent()
```

Comment: Thank you man, it is working. but can you explain what this function `makeCurrent()` is doing?

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide a link to the [`QOpenGLWidget::makeCurrent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#makeCurrent) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`glReadPixels` requires a render context to be current on the thread. Qt does automatic context managment and it's well documented that outside of methods named `…GL` the context may not be current.

You must make the context current explicitly outside of those methods, for which the Qt OpenGL classes offer the methods `makeCurrent` and `doneCurrent`. Brace your call of `glReadPixels` with calls to these functions; make sure to check, that `makeCurrent` succeeds, as the context may already be current in a different thread.

Comment: @AnkitKumarVerma: G.M. already gave you the code, my answer gives you the explanation. `makeCurrent` – well – makes the OpenGL context current on the calling thread.